# MYSQL SUM by QTY's And Values

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if its possible to get 2 sums from one query using the table values and then add them togther.

Here is some simple table & data which might help.

```
    CREATE TABLE `cartcontents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(30,2) NOT NULL,
  `cart_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `zone` (`zone_code`,`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records 
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `cartcontents` VALUES ('5', '011242077783866125432', '1', '36.00', '2');
INSERT INTO `cartcontents` VALUES ('4', '011242077793513596890', '3', '33.00', '4');
INSERT INTO `cartcontents` VALUES ('6', '011242077649557011493', '1', '110.00', '4');
INSERT INTO `cartcontents` VALUES ('7', '011242077724922511037', '1', '177.00', '5');
```

So I would like to be able collect the total qty & total value for a given cart_id.

So this would mean if I had 3 in the qty filed the sum would need to be (qty * price) for each zone then add them in total for the cart_id.

So in the above example if I was looking for the values for cart_id 4 The values I would hope I could return would be qty = 4 & total value = 209

Hope this makes sense and thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty, SUM(qty * price) AS total
FROM cartcontents
GROUP BY cart_id
```

Comment: Fantastic. Cant believe such a simple Query !